# Email recommendations Marketing cloud - Commerce Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, commerce-cloud

Do I need to have Commerce Cloud in order to use Einstein Email Recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: Email recs does not need Commerce Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Marketing Cloud Einstein operates on any platform. Although Commerce Cloud offers "Einstein," it is a different beast.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.marketing_cloud_einstein.htm&type=5